# Capturing user activity from a site

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics

In my organization, we have multiple web sites running. One team has developed a framework that now every web application is asked to use which captures following details:

1. How many times a page was clicked
2. Which user logged in and at what time
3. What kind of pages user is hitting (Retail, Banking, Oil & gas etc)
4. What is the frequent of his visit

and there are multiple such parameters.

I am sure such libraries and framework already exists. What are some of the best frameworks that captures this kind of details.

Thanks

Comment: This describes every web analytics system there is, so you need to specify more requirements (self-hosted vs. SaaS, proprietary vs. open source, commercial vs. free, how scalable does it need to be, should it run with/without javascript etc.)

Comment: @EikePierstorff: Thank you quick reply. Honestly, I was not aware that I need to consider so many parameters. The tool can be commercial, it should be secure & should be scalable.